# Cookies are there, but i can't get them in CodeIgniter. Why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

Codeigniter: When user logs in I want to save a cookie containing email.

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'email',
    'value'  => $email,
    'expire' => time()+3600*24*30*30,
    //'domain' => '.racebooking.net',
    'path'   => '/',
    'secure' => TRUE
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Once this code runs, f i look in Firebug i can see the cookie has been properly set. Here is what i see:

```
name     value                            domain                    raw size    path  expires                Security
email    fontanavideostudios@gmail.com    www.test.racebooking.net  36 B        /     07/09/2062 20:50:15    Secure
```

Unfortunately, when i try to retrieve it as follows

```
$this->input->cookie('email', TRUE);
```

I get nothing at all. The cookie is there, but i can't get it in CI. Any idea why? The website is installed in `www.test.racebooking.net` (a subdomain i use for testing before going on production)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, (I think) I found the problem! By setting `.racebooking.net` as domain, instead of leaving it blank (and, hence, automatically setting as `www.test.racebooking.net`) i fixed it.

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'email',
    'value'  => $email,
    'expire' => time()+3600*24*30*30,
    'domain' => '.racebooking.net',
    'path'   => '/',
    'secure' => TRUE
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Now i can retrieve cookie values.
The **"why does this happen"** question remains still open.

Answer (score 0):

```
cookie('some_cookie');
```

The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist.

Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

There is also:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: Ok, so CI thinks the cookie doesn't exist. The question is why can i see it in firebug? It means it exists

Comment: try loading the helper `$this->load->helper('cookie');` and then using `set_cookie($cookie);` and `get_cookie('email');`

Comment: Nope, nothing changes

Comment: Tried using sessions instead? Or instead of an array => `$this->input->set_cookie('name', 'value', 3600); //expires in one hour`